# pass by reference but reference to data and not to variable

Tags: ruby, language-agnostic, pass-by-reference

This is psesudo code. In what programming language this is possible ?

```
def lab(input)
  input = ['90']
end

x = ['80']
lab(x)

puts x #=> value of x has changed from ['80'] to ['90]
```

I have written this in ruby but in ruby I get the final x value of 80
because ruby is pass-by-reference. However what is passed is the
reference to the data held by x and not pointer to x itself
same is true in JavaScript. So I am wondering if there is any
programming language where the following is true.

Answer (score 1):

There are several languages that support pass-by-reference: it was implicit in most Fortran versions for longer than most other programming languages have *existed* (some versions used copies back and forth, but the end result had better be the same;-), it was specified by `var` in Pascal in the '70s (though the default, if you didn't say `var`, was by copy), etc, etc.

Most modern languages (Java, Python, Ruby, Javascript, Go, ...) uniformly pass (and assign) by *object*-reference (which is what you call "reference to data"), though some are more complex and let you specify more precisely what you want (e.g., C++, C#).

Comment: "reference to data" . First time I heard this term but seems like an apt name. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

So in Ruby, you can't make `x` reference another object from within a method, but you can change the object itself, in your case what you want can be achieved using mutating methods ([`Array#replace`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/replace) could be handy in case of arrays, for example):

```
def lab input
  input.replace ['90']
end

x = ['80']
#=> ["80"]
lab x
#=> ["90"]
x
#=> ["90"]
```

Comment: The point being that your problem wasn't in passing the variable, it was that `input = ['90']` reassigns the local variable 'input' to a new array object. `input.replace` changes the contents of the existing object, which is what you were trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you; I stated at the beginning that one can't reassign variable `x` from within the method in Ruby, just mutate its content.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to make it work in Ruby using bindings as reference:

```
def lab(input, bnd)
  eval "#{input} = 90", bnd
end

x = 80
lab("x", binding)
```

More information at: http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/RubyBindings.rdoc

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in a language with true pass-by-reference.

C#

```
public void lab(ref string[] input) {
  input = new string[] {"90"};
}

string[] x = {"80"};
lab(x);
```

PHP

```
function lab(&$input) {
  $input = array('90');
}

$x = array('80');
lab($x);
```

C++

```
void lab(string *&input) {
  input = new string[1];
  input[0] = "90";
}

string *x = new string[1];
x[0] = "80";
lab(x);
```

Perl

```
sub lab {
  $_[0] = ['90'];
}

$x = ['80'];
lab($x);
```